# Expected value conditioned on highest signal

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $v\sim N(0,\sigma_v^2)$, let $z, y_1, \dots, y_n\sim N(v, \sigma^2)$ be i.i.d stochastic variables.

Calculate $E[v\mid z, z \geq y_i \  \forall i \in \{1,\dots , n\}]$

Said in another way, then there are $n+1$ agents who all have a noisy signal about the value $v$. The player with the highest signal, knows his signal and he knows that he has the highest signal. What is the expected value of $v$, conditioned on his information? Is it necessary for him to know the true distribution of $v$?

Comment: We have $n+1$ i.i.d stochastic variables with distribution $N(v, \sigma^2)$, i.e mean $v$. The maximal one of these, I denote that $z$, I know the value of that, but not the other. However, I know that $z$ is the maximal. 

You could see it as $v$ is drawn first, and after $v$ has been drawn, the other variables can be drawn from their distribution. It might be more correct to say, that conditioned on $v$, they follow that distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the properties of conditional expectation, we have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(v|z,\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}) &= \frac{\mathbb{E}(v\mathbf{1}_{\{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}\}}|z) }{\mathbb{P}(\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}|z)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(v\mathbf{1}_{\{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}\}}|z,v)|z) }{\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}}|z)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(v\mathbf{1}_{\{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}\}}|z,v)|z) }{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}}|z,v)|z)}\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
The numerator of $(1)$:
$$\begin{align}
N&:=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(v\mathbf{1}_{\{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}\}}|z,v)|z)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(v\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}\}}|z,v)|z)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(v\left(\int_{-\infty}^z\frac{e^{-\frac{(t-v)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}dt  \right)^n|z\right)\\
&=\int_{u\in\mathbb{R}}\left(u\left(\int_{-\infty}^z\frac{e^{-\frac{(t-u)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}dt  \right)^n\varphi\left({\frac{u+z}{\sigma_v}}\right)\right)du\\
\end{align}$$
where $\varphi(\cdot)$ is the density function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Indeed, the density function of $v|z$ is determined as follows
$$z\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} v+\sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)\implies v|z \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} z - \sigma\mathcal{N}(0,1)\implies f_{v|z}(u)=\varphi\left(\frac{u+z}{\sigma_v}  \right)$$

A simpler representation of $N$ is
$$N = \int_{u\in\mathbb{R}}u\Phi^n\left(\frac{z-u}{\sigma}\right)\varphi\left({\frac{u+z}{\sigma_v}}\right)du$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the probability function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

By similar technique, the denominator of $(1)$ is equal to:
$$D:=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n}}|z,v)|z)=\int_{u\in\mathbb{R}}\Phi^n\left(\frac{z-u}{\sigma}\right)\varphi\left({\frac{u+z}{\sigma_v}}\right)du$$
We conclude that:
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{E}(v|z,\{y_i\le z\}_{i=1,...,n})  = \frac{\int_{u\in\mathbb{R}}u\Phi^n\left(\frac{z-u}{\sigma}\right)\varphi\left({\frac{u+z}{\sigma_v}}\right)du}{\int_{u\in\mathbb{R}}\Phi^n\left(\frac{z-u}{\sigma}\right)\varphi\left({\frac{u+z}{\sigma_v}}\right)du}}$$

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @JakobLarsen You're welcome!